# Android Java, onResume override

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am only starting with Java/Android and trying to implement custom SDK.
I am making Capacitor plugin for android, but for now trying to do  Android side logic.

I  have method that I want to be able to execute on demand `AndroidConfigManager.stopDetection(getActivity());` which enables/disables NFC read.

so If I execute `AndroidConfigManager.stopDetection(getActivity());` I get `NFC Detection Enabled` in log and all is good.

However that executes every time app goes to background and resumes after.  I've tried to override onPause and onResume but the way I have it doesn't seem to be doing anything.
I can't figure out how to suppress it

```
public class ExamplePlugin extends Plugin implements IDetectCardCallback, IITSOFrameworkCallback, ITransactionControllerCallback {
   private Application app;
   private Context context;

   public void echo(PluginCall call) {
        String value = call.getString("value");
        app = getActivity().getApplication();
        context = getContext();
        AndroidConfigManager.initialise(app);
        AndroidConfigManager.stopDetection(getActivity());

   }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        AndroidConfigManager.stopDetection(getActivity());
       // ITSOFramework.getInstance().detectCard(this, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
       // ITSOFramework.getInstance().detectCard(null, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Need more details like onCreate method where this started and where context is updated.

Comment: That's the problem,  I don't know how to find where is that happening. I think I am attaching it to `app = getActivity().getApplication();` but then I don't know how to override onResume on app